# loop through subviews not finding custom text field class...?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am trying to loop through subviews once a user taps 'sign up' to find and validate all text fields. The text fields are a custom class. No text fields are being found in the loop. what could be the problem? The text fields are added in interface builder storyboard and the class HAS been set properly

outlets in viewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: LoginTextFields!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: LoginTextFields!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: LoginTextFields!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmTextField: LoginTextFields!
```

I tried:

```
   private func validateTF() {
   print("validate")

    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let tf = view as? LoginTextFields {
            print("found one")
            if tf.isEmpty(){
                //alert
            } else if tf.tag == 2 && !tf.isValidEmail(email: emailTextField.text!) {
                //alert
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
  for view in self.view.subviews {
        print(view)
        if view.isKind(of: LoginTextFields.self) {
            print("tf found")
            let tf = view as! LoginTextFields
            if tf.isEmpty() {
                //alert
            } else if tf.tag == 2 && !tf.isValidEmail(email: emailTextField.text!) {
                //alert
            }
            print("nps")
        }
    }
```

Comment: How were the text fields added to the view controller's view? Through code? Storyboard? Do you have outlets or properties referencing the text fields?

Comment: @rmaddy updated with code and info! added thru storyboard and custom class is definitely set and classes match up

Comment: If you have outlets, why are you writing a loop to find them? You already have access to them.

Comment: @rmaddy i wanted a more elegant solution than a bunch of redundant "if tf.text == "" || ....

Comment: Then update your question clearly explaining that. You have outlets. You don't need to search for the fields. So your actual question is how to efficiently check all of their values. Post your inefficient code so we can see what can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not going to answer your question specifically I’m going to offer a (much better) alternative.

Don’t use tags on views... ever. Their use encourages really bad patterns. Like looping through views to get email text fields.

Instead you should create a property for each of your text fields.

`let emailTextField: LoginTextField = someTextField`

Etc...

That way you don’t need a loop. You just check the email text field and then the password text field and so on.

**After your edit...**

You already have the properties there. So why are you looping through anything?

Just check the properties.

Comment: @user7804097 if you want to do something more elegant you could add a function to your text field class like `isValid` and then just do `blah.isValid` or something like that. Then you don’t have to repeat your code. You just check the function on each one.

Comment: duhhh lol. thanks...but isnt it still weird that it doesnt find it..?

Comment: @user7804097 It depends on how you views and view hierarchy is set up. Iterating through subviews will only go “one layer” deep. If you have a hierarchy like ... `view - otherView - textField` then iterating `view.subviews` will not find your text fields.